# Java BufferedReader receives null string

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, printwriter

My program is laid out so that the main app can send commands to any node connected to it. When a node receives a request, it returns a response and continues to wait for more requests.

When the app is run the node successfully replies to one request, and when a second request is sent the node sees it as a null or does not see it at all. Why does this keep happening?

P.S. I want the connection to the node to stay open, so that it can receive more requests.

Request sending code:

```
public java.lang.String getTime(server.Node node){

    protocol.Message ms = new protocol.Message("<time>","");

    node.sendRequestToClient(ms);
    node.dos.flush();

    java.lang.System.out.println("Sent time request to " + node.ip);

    java.lang.String time = null;
    try {

        time = node.dis.readLine();


    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not read response.");
    }

    protocol.Message response = protocol.Message.parseDataToMessage(time);

    java.lang.String systime = response.getActionData();

    return systime;


}
```

Response sending code:

```
public class Client {

public Client(NetworkConnection connection){


    this.connectionToServer = connection;

    try{
        connectionToServer.connect();
        responseOutStream = connectionToServer.getPrintWriter();
        requestInStream = connectionToServer.getBufferedReader();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Could not connect to server." + ex.getMessage() + ex.toString());
    }



}

public void beginRequestListener(){

    String request;

    try {
        while((request = requestInStream.readLine())!=""){


            System.out.println("Recieved request: " + request + request.length());

            Message response = Message.parseDataToMessage(request);

            sendResponseToServer(response);
    }


    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not read request stream.");
    } catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getClass();
    }

}

public void sendResponseToServer(Message ms){

        protocol.Message response = MessageParser.compileResponse(ms);
        java.lang.System.out.println("Response to send: "+response);
        response.send(responseOutStream);



}



public BufferedReader requestInStream; 
public PrintWriter responseOutStream; 
public NetworkConnection connectionToServer;
```

}

MessageParser class:

```
public class MessageParser {



static public Message compileResponse(Message ms){

    Message response = null;

    switch(ms.getAction()){

        case "<time>":

            response = new Message("<time>", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            break;

        case "<date>":

            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
            Date date = new Date();
            sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));



            response = new Message("<date>", date.toString());
            break;    



        default:

            break;

    }
    return response;
}
```

}

The stack trace and output:

```
Recieved request: <action><time><action><actionData><actionData>
Response to send: <action><time><action><actionData>1370380854566<actionData>

Recieved request: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at protocol.MessageParser.compileResponse(MessageParser.java:23)
at client.Client.sendResponseToServer(Client.java:67)
at client.Client.beginRequestListener(Client.java:52)
at client.ClientInterface.main(ClientInterface.java:107)
```

Message class:

public class Message {

```
public Message(String data){



}

public Message(String action, String actionData){

    this.action = action;
    this.actionData = actionData;

}

 public void send(PrintWriter connection){

    try{
        connection.println(this.toString());
        connection.flush();
        //System.out.println(this.toString());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Could not send Message.");
    }


}

@java.lang.Override
public String toString(){

    return  
           action_marker + action + action_marker +
           actionData_marker + actionData + actionData_marker +
           eof_marker;

}

public static Message parseDataToMessage(String data){


    Message ms = null;
    if(data.isEmpty() == false){
    int begin_action_marker = data.indexOf("<action>")+8;
    int end_action_marker = data.lastIndexOf("<action>");

    String action = data.substring(begin_action_marker, end_action_marker);

    int begin_actionData_marker = data.indexOf("<actionData>")+12;
    int end_actionData_marker = data.lastIndexOf("<actionData>");

    String actionData = data.substring(begin_actionData_marker, end_actionData_marker);

    ms = new Message(action, actionData);



    }

    return ms;

}

public void setAction(String action){
    this.action = action;

}

public String getActionData(){
    return actionData;

}

public String getAction(){
    return action;

}

public void setActionData(String action){
    this.actionData = action;

}

public String eof_marker = "\r\n";

public String action;
public String action_marker = "<action>";

public String actionData;   
public String actionData_marker = "<actionData>";
```

}

Comment: What is line 23 in MessageParser? and I assume you are using `JDK 7`

Comment: At first glance, the only thing that can be null in `compileResponse` is `ms`... Which comes from `Message response = Message.parseDataToMessage(request);`

Comment: Line 23 is the switch statement.

Comment: The problem is it works the first time, the somehow receives a second request immediately after the first (a null request).

Comment: @TimS. You need to show the `parseDataToMessage` method - that is where the `null` comes from.

Comment: @assylias The node should not receive two requests at once, when only one request was sent from the main app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

- you receive an empty request in `(request = requestInStream.readLine())`
- this goes to `Message.parseDataToMessage(request);` which returns `null` for empty requests
- that generates a NullPointerException in `compileResponse`

The (likely) solution: change this

```
while((request = requestInStream.readLine())!=""){
```

into this:

```
while(!(request = requestInStream.readLine()).isEmpty())
```

Why your code does not work: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

> while((request = requestInStream.readLine())!=""){

What's this test for? Are you expecting empty requests? You shouldn't be. If you get one it's a bug at the sender.

However you must test the result of `readLine()` for null before doing anything else with it. The line should read:

```
while((request = requestInStream.readLine())!= null){
```